# Subplotting an enlarged section of a fits image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy, fits

I'm attempting to open up an astronomical image and plot it as a figure, which is done by my code, however, I am trying to enlarge a section of the fits file as a subplot on the same figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.visualization import astropy_mpl_style
plt.style.use(astropy_mpl_style)
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
from astropy.io import fits
image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('814wmos.fits')

image_data = fits.getdata('814wmos.fits', ext=0)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
```

This gives me my fits file, and plots it, which without 'zooming' in on the coordinates[350:450,500:600] shows/ tells me very little. How can I plot this area as a subplot next to original image, of the same size (zoomed in for same axes)?

Comment: Have you looked [at matplotlib's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) for `inset_locator` and `inset_axes`?

Comment: also recent matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-zoom-inset-axes-py